# Create text outline on canvas in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, text, canvas, outline

How can I give a text an outline in JavaScript when drawing on the Canvas? See image below of what I try to do.

[image]

Comment: I tried the shadow, see [jsFiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/NMEMa/) but the shadow is just too thin. I also tried two (or more) textfields behind each other, but that didn't work either. Got other ideas?

Comment: Someone showed me the [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/ybJM4/4/)

Answer (score 7):

Daniel Langh showed me the solution:

```
var txt = 'Hello World!';
var x = 30,
    y = 50;

context.font = "40px Helvetica";

context.strokeStyle = 'white';

// setup these to match your needs
context.miterLimit = 2;
context.lineJoin = 'circle';

// draw an outline, then filled
context.lineWidth = 7;
context.strokeText(txt, x, y);
context.lineWidth = 1;
context.fillText(txt, x, y);
```

Comment: I was having the same problem and I saw this answer. The `miterLimit` option fixed the line spikes, but I was most satisfied with just `context.lineJoin = 'round';`

Comment: YES!  I'm so happy to have the 'spikes' issue resolved with such a simple parameter setting.  I wrote a function which produced smooth large strokes but it required absurd amounts of CPU time depending on the browser.  Stroke spikes be gone! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using strokeText to stroke an outline:

```
var context = document.getElementById("d").getContext("2d");

context.font = "bold 34px sans-serif";
context.fillText('office space', 50, 60);
context.strokeStyle = 'white';
context.lineWidth = 2;
context.strokeText('office space', 50, 60);
```

Comment: That's something, but not quite what I'm looking for. See here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NMEMa/)